Error when using required field in schema in mongoose
//controller:
const Product = require("../models/productModel");
//Create product
exports.createProduct = async (req, res, next) => {
  const product = await Product.create(req.body);

  res.status(201).json({
    success: true,
    product,
  });
};

productModel.js:
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const productSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,//err here.
  },
})

There is an answer at link but those do not fix my error.
Here is the request that I send:
http://localhost:4000/api/v1/product/new (POST request with JSON content)
JSON:
{
    "name":"Vaseline petrolatum Jelly"
}

The above code gives the below error:
this.$__.validationError = new ValidationError(this);
^
ValidationError: Product validation failed: name: Path name is required.
at Document.invalidate (C:\Users\DELL\Downloads\react-learn\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:3289:32)
at C:\Users\DELL\Downloads\react-learn\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:3050:17
at C:\Users\DELL\Downloads\react-learn\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schemaType.js:1388:9
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:77:11) {
errors: {
name: ValidatorError: Path name is required.
at validate (C:\Users\DELL\Downloads\react-learn\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schemaType.js:1385:13)
at SchemaType.doValidate (C:\Users\DELL\Downloads\react-learn\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schemaType.js:1369:7)
at C:\Users\DELL\Downloads\react-learn\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:3042:18
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:77:11) {
properties: {
validator: [Function (anonymous)],
message: 'Path name is required.',
type: 'required',
path: 'name',
fullPath: undefined,
value: undefined
},
kind: 'required',
path: 'name',
value: undefined,
reason: undefined,
[Symbol(mongoose#validatorError)]: true
}
},
_message: 'Product validation failed'
}
I tried the solutions at link but none of them worked for me.

Please provide your JS code that insert this document to DB

I used express.json() in app.js but it was down below another line:
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
const product = require("./routes/productRoute");
app.use("/api/v1", product);
//it was previously here somewhere.
module.exports = app;

